# Video parameters on which the execution time depends

Tags: ffmpeg

For example, I have command:

`ffmpeg -ss 100 -i input.avi -t 10 -c copy -y output.mp4`

Does the execution time of this command depend on video quality, fps, -ss value, or maybe something else?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

All this command does is copy the streams, so it depends mainly on file size, disk I/O & RAM speed.

Comment: But if the execution time depends on the file size, does it depend on the video quality, fps and duration? I've conducted 2 experiments: I cut 70 fragments from video with 544x400 quality, fps = 23.98, duration ~ 25 minutes and cut 70 fragments from video with 1920x960 quality, fps = 25, duration ~ 55min. The time stamps were the same in both cases. As a result, the execution time is similar in both cases, and I don't understand why this is happening. To rule out chance, I've conducted these experiments several times.

Comment: Share the command you actually ran.

Comment: I am using Node.js to spawn ffmpeg processes asynchronously, so in both cases I ran the above command in a loop. For any number of loop iterations (10, 20, ..., 70), the elapsed time is approximately the same in both cases.